# Explanation needed with AES_cfb128_encrypt() function

Tags: c++, linux, ssl, encryption, aes

Hey I'm looking for some explanation regarding

```
void AES_cfb128_encrypt(const unsigned char *in, unsigned char *out, size_t length,
                        const AES_KEY *key, unsigned char *ivec, int *num, int enc)
```

I understand the straightforward variables like
`in` is our input buffer
`out` is our output buffer
`length` is size of our input/number of bytes of input buffer
`key` is pointer to our key which we set by AES_set_encrypt_key
`enc` is the mode we want(whether encryption or decryption)

However, I don't understand what ivec and num do.
I just know (might be wrong) is that ivec stands for initial vector and another thing in a code that i found online there was a comment:
`/* set where on the 128 bit encrypted block to begin encryption*/`. At first, I thought this left gaps of unencrypted data in the midst of encrypted one, but that wasn't the case when I looked at the byte values while debugging and printing values.

Comment: ivec protects the second time you encrypt the same message.

Answer (score 0):

`ivec` is an Initialisation Vector and commonly written as IV. The keyword is the [probabilistic encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_encryption);

If the encryption is not probabilistic then when you re-encrypt a message under the same key, you will get the same result and an eavesdropper will notice this. This is a simple attack, in some modes, this is more catastrophic like CTR mode where encryption of two messages under the same IV can cause loss of confidentiality.

In CFB mode, if you encrypt two different messages then the first blocks are under attack where the attacker gets x-or of the messages.

One should generate random IV's per message since the [IV must be unpredictable](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38a.pdf) for CFB mode ( as in CBC mode).

Note that, you need to send the IV to the receiver so that the decryption works. The IV need not be secret, one can prepend it to cyphertext.

Don't forget that, those are archaic mode of operation, in modern cryptography we prefer authenticated encryption modes like AES-GCM, AES-CCM, and ChaCha20-Poly1305.

And, the key is still secure even if you don't generate random per message!